# Why doesn't my subroutine return value get assigned to $_ default variable

Tags: perl

I have a Perl subroutine which updates an RSS feed. I want to test the returned value, but the function is used in many places so I wanted to just test the default variable `$_` which as far as I understand should be the assigned the return value if no variable is specified.

The code is a bit too long to include all of it, but in essence it does the following

```
sub updateFeed {
  #....
  if($error) {
    return 0;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Why then does

```
$rtn = updateFeed("My message");
if ($rtn < 1) { &Log("updateFeed Failed with error $rtn"); }
```

NOT log any error

whereas

```
updateFeed("myMessage");
if ($_ < 1) { &Log("updateFeed Failed with error $_"); }
```

logs an error of "`updateFeed Failed with error`"? (Note no value at the end of the message.)

Can anyone tell me why the default variable seems to contain an empty string or undef?

Comment: Note that the `&` in front of function names is not normally needed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because Perl doesn't work that way. `$_` doesn't automatically get the result of functions called in void context. There are some built-in operators that read and write `$_` and `@_` by default, but your own subroutines will only do that if you write code to make it happen.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I was under the impression that it was a truly default value for all assignments and return values.

Answer (score 8):

An ordinary function call is not one of the contexts in which `$_` is used implicitly.

Here's what `perldoc perlvar` (as of v5.14.1) has to say about `$_`:

> $_
>   The default input and pattern-searching space. The following pairs are equivalent:

```
    while (<>) {...}    # equivalent only in while!
    while (defined($_ = <>)) {...}

    /^Subject:/
    $_ =~ /^Subject:/

    tr/a-z/A-Z/
    $_ =~ tr/a-z/A-Z/

    chomp     
    chomp($_)
```

> Here are the places where Perl will assume $_ even if you don't use it:
>
> - The following functions use $_ as a default argument:
>
>   abs, alarm, chomp, chop, chr, chroot, cos, defined, eval, exp, glob, hex, int, lc, lcfirst, length, log, lstat, mkdir, oct, ord, pos, print, quotemeta, readlink, readpipe, ref, require,
>     reverse (in scalar context only), rmdir, sin, split (on its second argument), sqrt, stat, study, uc, ucfirst, unlink, unpack.
> - All file tests (`-f`, `-d`) except for `-t`, which defaults to STDIN.  See `-X` in perlfunc
> - The pattern matching operations `m//`, `s///` and `tr///` (aka `y///`) when used without an `=~` operator.
> - The default iterator variable in a `foreach` loop if no other variable is supplied.
> - The implicit iterator variable in the `grep()` and `map()` functions.
> - The implicit variable of `given()`.
> - The default place to put an input record when a `<FH>` operation's result is tested by itself as the sole criterion of a `while` test. Outside a `while` test, this will not happen.
>
> As $_ is a global variable, this may lead in some cases to unwanted side-effects. As of perl 5.9.1, you can now use a lexical version of $_ by declaring it in a file or in a block with `my`.
>   Moreover, declaring `our $_` restores the global $_ in the current scope.
>
> Mnemonic: underline is understood in certain operations.

Comment: Thats really detailed, thanks for the effort put in. I'll try to remember this for future

Comment: @Wassy: It was mostly copy-and-paste from the manual (though I did have to tweak the formatting quite a bit).

Answer (score 5):

You never assigned the flag to `$_`, so why would it contain your flag? It appears to contain an empty string (or perhaps `undef`, which stringifies to the empty string with a warning).

Comment: No I wasn't expecting it to contain the error message. I was however, under the misapprehension that it would be automatically assigned the last returned subroutine value (kind of like $? in bash). But as mentioned, this was incorrect.

Comment: Oops, that's what I meant. Anyway, there's nothing special about `$_` (except that it refers to the same variable no matter which package you're in).

Answer (score 0):

[`$_`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24_) isn't by set by subroutines in void context by default. It is possible to write your subs to set [`$_`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24_) when is void context. You start by checking the value of [`wantarray`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/wantarray.html), and set [`$_`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24_) when [`wantarray`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/wantarray.html) is undefined.

```
sub updateFeed {
  ...
  my $return
  ...

  if($error) {
    $return = 0;
  }else{
    $return = 1;
  }
  # $return = !$error || 0;

  if( defined wantarray ){ # scalar or list context
    return $return;
  }else{ # void context
    $_ = $return;
  }
}
```

I would recommend against doing this as it can be quite a surprise to someone that is using your subroutine. Which can make it harder to debug their program.

About the only time I would do this, is when emulating a [built-in subroutine](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html).